# Restricting view to content associated with user profile

Tags: users, views

On my site some users have the permission to see others' profile.

I'm looking to show a view in a block containing a *food* content type. It will be displayed on the profile page of the users (user/*). The block will contain content associated with that user (somehow I need to tell that when I am creating the content).

For example: Content "rice" belongs to user1; content "potatoes" belong to user2.

When I enter the user1's profile I see "rice"; when I enter user2 profile I see "potatos". It's the same block with the information changing according to the user profile I am seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're wanting is a contextual filter for your view. Create a node view with a block display and in the **Advanced** section under **Contextual Filter** click the **Add** button.

From there you can add *Content: Author uid* which will tell the view to filter by author UID. On the popup modal, under the **WHEN THE FILTER IS NOT....** fieldset, select *Provide default value* with **Type** of *Raw value from URL* and **Path** component of *2*. This essentially tells the view to pull the UID from Drupal's internal path (i.e. the *XXX* in **/user/XXX** when viewing a user page).

After saving the view, you should be able to place it your region to display against user profile pages.